# Is there a way to change the TeX engine from PDFLaTeX to XeLaTeX in Ipe?

Tags: xetex, ipe

In my document, I have to use XeLaTeX to get the output. On the other hand, I'm using [`Ipe`](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net) to  produce some graphic files with some labels on them. I want to have these labels in Persian. Is there a way to change the TeX engine from pdfLaTeX to XeLaTeX in Ipe?

Answer (score 5):

I do not think it is possible without rewriting Ipe.  It is hardcoded in the source, and since Ipe parses the `.pdf` created by pdfLaTeX, it expects the `.pdf` file to be generated by actual pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX output would probably confuse it.

You can try to download the source, in the `src/ipelib/platform.cpp` file replace all occurrences of `pdflatex` by `xelatex`, and compile Ipe, but I would be very surprised if that worked.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible,  you can write a shell script / batch file, name it "pdflatex",
and put the path to the directory containing the script in IPELATEXPATH.